# Глобальный хук на дополнительные кнопки мыши.

Tags: c#, winapi, сниппет, hotkeys

У меня на мышке есть две дополнительные кнопки, хотелось бы установить горячие клавиши на них, но мне непонятно как узнать их название или код.
Глобальную горячую клавишу устанавливаю следующим способом:

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace GlobalHotKeysExperiments
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        [DllImport("User32.dll")]
        public static extern bool RegisterHotKey(IntPtr hWnd, int id, uint fsModifiers, uint vk);

        [DllImport("User32.dll")]
        public static extern bool UnregisterHotKey(IntPtr hWnd, int id);

        [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
        public static extern Int16 GlobalAddAtom(string name);

        [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
        public static extern Int16 GlobalDeleteAtom(Int16 nAtom);

        Int16 atom = GlobalAddAtom("PFight");

        public Form1()
        {
            bool state = RegisterHotKey(this.Handle, atom, Defines.MOD_CONTROL, (uint)Keys.Tab);
            InitializeComponent();
            this.FormClosing += new FormClosingEventHandler(Form1_FormClosing);

        }

        void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
        {
            UnregisterHotKey(this.Handle, atom);
            GlobalDeleteAtom(atom);
        }

        protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
        {
            if (m.Msg == 0x0312 //WM_HOTKEY
                && m.WParam == atom) 
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Yahooo!");
            }
            base.WndProc(ref m);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Всё оказалось намного проще, вот готовая реализация глобального хука на 4 кнопку:

```
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

public class Form1 : Form
{
    [DllImport("User32.dll")]
    private static extern short GetAsyncKeyState(System.Windows.Forms.Keys vKey);

    public Form1()
    {
        MethodInvoker mi = new MethodInvoker(WaitKey);
        mi.BeginInvoke(null, null);
    }

    private void WaitKey()
    {
        while (this.IsHandleCreated)
        {
            //XButton1 или XButton2 соответственно 4 и 5 кнопки
            int res1 = Convert.ToInt32(GetAsyncKeyState(Keys.XButton1).ToString());
            if (res1 != 0)
                MessageBox.Show("Hello");
        }
    }
}
```

Еще вариант (пример ловит нажатие Shitf+A):

```
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

    public class Form1 : Form
    {
        [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet=CharSet.Auto, ExactSpelling=true)]
        internal static extern short GetAsyncKeyState(int vkey);

        public Form1()
        {
            MethodInvoker mi = new MethodInvoker(WaitKey);
            mi.BeginInvoke(null, null);
        }

        private void WaitKey()
        {
            while (this.IsHandleCreated)
            {
                short res1 = GetAsyncKeyState(VK_SHIFT);
                short res2 = GetAsyncKeyState(VK_A);
                if (res1 != 0 && res2 != 0)
                    MessageBox.Show("Hello");
            }
        }

        public const int VK_SHIFT = 0x10;
        public const int VK_A = 0x41;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Windows API сам по себе не поддерживает мыши с дополнительными кнопками. Их поддерживает драйвер производителя. Поэтому в первую очередь надо смотреть в спецификацию драйвера той мыши, которой вы собираетесь воспользоваться.

Пример работы с дополнительными кнопками в C#: [How to use your extra mouse buttons in games or apps](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/23756/How-to-use-your-extra-mouse-buttons-in-games-or-ap). В статье отлавливаются сообщения `WM_USER` (автор выяснил это с помощью Spy++), рассылаемые драйвером, и вместо них эмулируются нажатия функциональных клавиш.